# Document for component manangement

Tags: documentation

We have lots of reusable component [software] in our organization. I have a task to explain/define/elaborate in them a document [probably, a reusable component document]. But I am unable to get such kind of document on Internet.

Does anyone of you have a document in which I can document reusable component [technically/functionally]?

Comment: Any help for .NET component management document ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention the language, but many have tools like Java's Javadoc.   Some of these are stand-alone and relatively language agnostic. This allows the documentation to be placed in the code where it has a better chance of being up to date.  Automated tools then scan the source code and generate output (usually web pages) that can be read by developers and others.

Comment: My bad! I have .NET components for documentation. But Javadoc is something I should know about, no matter I am from any other technology. +1.